# Problems with accessing data from Google Calendar API

Tags: java, eclipse, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I want to get a users calendar events (entries) via the **java** [google calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) (V3.0). Unfortunately, I was unable to find any working example (tutorial) or successfully run anything. What I did so far:

- I checked the [APIs Explorer](http://code.google.com/apis/explorer/#_s=calendar&_v=v3) and successfully run some requests via the google website and my developer api key (conclusion: my API access works in theory).
- I tried to follow the "[Your first App](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/firstapp)"-guide. There are two ways to invoke the API: REST or client libraries. I want to use the java client library.
- So I tried to set up the [client library](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/setup) : downloaded the jars and added them to the build path (in eclipse) - as I usually do this with external jars. I now can import the classes without errors.
- Here, the guide finishes abruptly if I want to use the java client library instead of directly accessing it via REST...
- From here I have absolutely no idea what to do. I found a lot of examples in the web (usually for the v1.0 or v2.0 API), but was unable to run any of them. (On Google Developers I found [several examples](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Calendar_API), but all for Android or AppEngine. Nothing worked...)

Does anyone of you know a very simple example to get a users events via Java library (Google Code API)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it on my own. For all of you who want to start using the Google APIs in Eclipse. I highly recommend using Maven which immensely helps including the right jars (actually, it does it for you). Then try this example code ([link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate)) to start (OAuth2 authentication). You also will need a dev account and API key from google: [link](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=devconsole&passive=1209600&continue=https://code.google.com/apis/console/&followup=https://code.google.com/apis/console/). Then you can start coding :) enjoy!